# Angular : How to add property as object in json object?

Tags: javascript, angular, object

this.getdata() gives me data into below format.

```
{ 
   "MyRequest":{ 
      "Month":"",
      "Number":"003254810"
   }
}
```

I have another request where i want to pass above json propery into Myrequest.
How can i achieve that part? can someone help me for the same?

```
{
 "sol1" : 123,
 "MyRequest" : {

        }

}
```

Comment: This question should be close. Search in the internet how to use CRUD methods in Angular.

Comment: Hi Jess Thanks for the suggestion. its not just crud operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[]` to add `property` as below.

```js
var a = { 
   "MyRequest":{ 
      "Month":"",
      "Number":"003254810"
   }
};
var b = {};
b['sol1'] = 123;
b['MyRequest'] = a.MyRequest;
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare an `interface` for the shape of your request.

```
    export interface SecondRequest {
         solo: string;
         MyRequest: {
           Month: string;
           number: string;
         };
    }
```

and then, just assign `MyRequest` to your `SecondRequst` object.

```
secondRequest: SecondRequest = <SecondRequest>{};
...
this.secondRequest.MyRequest = MyRequest;
```